# split a string and store in an array of arrays

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I have the following piece of code (which splits a string by a delimiter)

```
void explode(const char *input, const char *delim)
{
    char *local = strdup(input);

    char *token;

    while ((token = strtok_r(local, delim, &local))) {
        puts(token);
    }
}
```

Instead of printing out the strings, I would like to have them stored in an array of arrays. I'm somewhat new to the more advanced concepts, I've been getting too much segfaults for hours. What would you do in this situation?

Comment: Can you post your code that segfaults? Let us see your attempt.

Answer (score 1):

You don't know the size of the array beforehand so you should initialize it to some fixed sensible size (say 16?) and keep an index variable to point to the next available slot in the array to store the next variable. If the index variable becomes equal to the array size, you need to use `realloc` to allocate more memory and update the size variable. Keep reallocating till you are done with the string. Here is some pseudo code:

```
size_t array_size = 16;
size_t index = 0;
char **arr = malloc(array_size * sizeof(char *));
while ((token = strtok_r(local, delim, &local))) {
        if (index == array_size) {
            array_size += 16;
            arr = realloc(arr, array_size * sizeof *arr);
            /* add error check */
        }  
        arr[index++] = token;
}
```

You should make sure that you free the memory allocated once you are done with it.